# React Typescript: It looks like you're trying to use TypeScript but do not have typescript installed

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to create a React application and I want to use a typescript in this application, at first I went to the React website in order to create an application using typescript and I found that I had to put this instruction in the terminal first:

```
npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript
```

And when it finished installing, I put it in the terminal:

```
npm start
```

But I got this error:

```
It looks like you're trying to use TypeScript but do not have typescript installed
```

I opened the terminal and wrote this instruction:

```
npm install
```

then i run the app:

```
npm start
```

But the error is still there

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved my problem with the following instruction:

```
npm install --save typescript @types/node @types/react @types/react-dom @types/jest
```

## or

```
yarn add typescript @types/node @types/react @types/react-dom @types/jest
```

Comment: Make sure you check what version of react you are using in your package.json. I received the "It looks like.." error when attempting to add typescript to a React17 project.   I had to pin my @types to version 17. E.g. :
npm install  --save-dev typescript  @types/react@17.0.0 @types/node@17.0.0 @types/react-dom@17.0.0

Answer (score 2):

Consider upgrading Next.js 11 to 12 or to latest version. Also, you need to upgrade types to latest for react and react-dom. Here is a brief documentation about that:

https://nextjs.org/docs/upgrading#upgrade-nextjs-version-to-12

Comment: I'm upvoting this because **it seems to be a bug in next.js 10** - asking for a package `@types/react` to be installed that is already installed (you can see this with `npm ls @types/react`) doesn't make sense. It may also be fixed in a newer version of next 10, but I haven't tried that.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried

```
npm install -g typescript
```

> yes i tryed but still with error

Have you tried

```
npm run start
```