# Unable to use typescript with expo - "It looks like you're trying to use TypeScript but don't have the required dependencies installed"

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, dependencies, expo

I am receiving an error while trying to use Typescript with my existing expo project.

While following the docs, I created a *tsconfig.json* file in the project root.

When running `expo start`, I am prompted to install the typescript dependencies.  However, after these are successfully installed (tick message appears in console: `√ Installed typescript@~4.3.5, @types/react@~17.0.21, @types/react-native@~0.67.6`), I receive the following error:

```js
It looks like you're trying to use TypeScript but don't have the required dependencies installed.

Please install @types/react by running:

yarn add --dev @types/react@~17.0.21

If you're not using TypeScript, please remove the TypeScript files from your project and delete the tsconfig.json.

error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

After following the instructions and running the `yarn add ....` command, I keep seeing the same error message.

I have tried deleting the *node_modules* folder and *package-lock.json* file to no avail.  I have also tried following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70106900/react-typescript-it-looks-like-youre-trying-to-use-typescript-but-do-not-have) answer.
Any assistance would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. Have you perhaps figured out a way to resolve this issue?

Comment: So, running ```yarn add expo-cli``` may fix the error, however this results in the local development server not starting up.  I can start the server by running ```expo start``` directly, rather than using ```yarn start```, but the error is back again!  Very odd.

Answer (score 14):

Just re-install expo-cli `npm install -g expo-cli`.

Answer (score 12):

Seems to be a bug. It works if I install `@types/react` on the specific version that Expo requests (`17.0.21`).

```
yarn add --dev @types/react@17.0.21
```

Comment: Apart some mismatch with old expo api with typescript could be then the issue?

Comment: Wow, this was true for me too. I'm using Next.js (not Expo), and originally my repo had `"@types/react": "^17.0.38",` and everything worked fine. Then suddenly my `yarn dev` wouldn't work even though I didn't have any changes to my code. I must have at some point let yarn install a newer version of @types/react and then reverted it, and I'd forgotten to delete the folder(s) from `node_modules` and do `yarn install` again.

Comment: Wow, this is so bizarre. It just happened for me again on another computer. To solve it, I ran `git checkout yarn.lock && rm -rf node_modules/@types/react && yarn add -D @types/react@17.0.38 && yarn install`. Basically this removed the ^ from `"@types/react": "^17.0.38"`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know which of the following worked, but I ran the following commands and the problem went away.

- `sudo npm install -g expo-cli`
- `sudo npm install -g @types/react`
- `sudo npm install -g @types/react-native`
- `sudo npm install -g typescript`

Comment: Seems like `sudo npm install -g expo-cli` (updating the Expo CLI) did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
yarn add expo-cli
```

solved for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I resolved it by :

1- delete the node_modules.

2-  update expo to the latest version using npm i -g expo-cli

hope this will help someone

Answer (score 1):

if you installed @types/react remove that from your dev dependencies

Answer (score 0):

I solved it running `YARN_CHECKSUM_BEHAVIOR=update yarn`